# PHP file_get_contents and CURL failure to fetch the content of a javascript based page

Tags: javascript, php, curl, web-scraping

I have tried both file_get_contents and CURL to fetch the content of a specific page. I setup the CURL to follow redirects and changed `User-Agent`, however, it did not work. I have no problem when loading page in browser. I get a page with below code whenever I try to fetch it with file_get_contents or CURL:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>Loading ...</title> <script 
src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </head> <html> <noscript>Enable java!</noscript> <div id="status"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> 
function check(){ $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/index.php",
    data: "allowed=5b91b80a061537ae6a23835aba38279e",
    success: function(html){if(html == "allowed"){location.reload();}},
    beforeSend:function(){
        $("#status").html("Loading ...")
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    check();
});
</script> </html>
```

Is there anyway to bypass such restriction **without** using Javascript based Web Scrapers like PhantomJs, CasperJs or ZombieJs? Simply using a plain PHP?

Comment: You can parse the contents of javascript you're getting and make another CURL request to ajax page.

Comment: @Inurosen What is the address of the ajax page? In the above sample page, how can I get the address of the next page? As you can see its type is `POST`, how can I form a URL from that?

Comment: `url: "/index.php",` it says

Comment: @Inurosen But If I go to the `/index.php` I will get another content which is not what I want.

Comment: Well, basically you send a POST request to `index.php`. There you will get a cookie, which you will have to use to continue browsing that site. Then just reload the page with cookies applied to your request.

Comment: @Inurosen So you mean I have to fetch `allowed=5b91b80a061537ae6a23835aba38279e` and make a post request to the `/index.php` after that I get a cookie which will help me to browse the current and other pages without burden?

Comment: Basically, yes. Good luck :)